# List of comment templates

Tags: discussion, comments

As the site matures, it seems like it might be a good idea to have some boilerplate comments that are likely to be needed on a fairly regular basis and that can be posted by site regulars as necessary. Examples of uses for such comments might be

- welcoming new users to the site to make them feel like they are joining a community
- notifying people of policies that the community agrees on, such as the policy on homework questions, on reference-only answers, etc.
- directing people to community wiki posts on the meta site that contain more information.

On the last point, it might also be a good idea to put up some community wikis on meta that serve as information pages with more detail on policies, FAQs etc. What I have in mind is something like [this example from TeX SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

If you have any thoughts on what might be useful comments, please post them below. Perhaps we could stick to one comment per answer so that we can vote on individual ideas.

Comment: I like the idea a lot, chiefly the information pages community wiki. If this post is meant to become the repository for comment templates, **may I suggest to change the title to "List of comment templates"** to ease browsing and searching?

Comment: Also, there are good resources on other SE for comment templates. See for instance : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates

Answer (score 3):

## General Welcome

> Welcome to Economics.SE! Please take the time to look at our [welcome page](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-sx) to learn how to get the most out of the community.

`Welcome to Economics.SE! Please take the time to look at our [welcome page](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-sx) to learn how to get the most out of the community.`

Answer (score 2):

## References without descriptions

> Thank you for providing these references. Please consider editing your answer to include a brief description of what they contain and how they answer the question. That ensures your answer will continue to be of maximum value to future visitors to *Economics.SE*.

or for posts with a single reference:

> Thank you for providing this reference. Please consider editing your answer to include a brief description of what it contains and how it answers the question. That ensures your answer will continue to be of maximum value to future visitors to *Economics.SE*.

Possible addition :

> Also, it would be better to cite more information, like the title and
>   authors. That way even if the link stops working, people can still
>   find the publication.

Here's another wording:

> Hello there and welcome. We're looking to build a body of awesome answers **right here**. That's why your post hasn't been well-received: it does not provide an answer - it just tells readers to leave this site and go somewhere else. While links in posts are great for providing external support for answers, they can't be answers in their own right. Please summarise the arguments made by the article, by editing them into your answer. That way, the answer will be useful, whatever happens to that hyperlink in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding Cross-posting**

> It appears that you have crossposted this question simultaneously on
>   `Another SE website` at `URL`. It is only permitted
>   to repost after sufficient time has passed and you have not obtained
>   the desired answer elsewhere, since simultaneous crossposting
>   duplicates effort and fractures discussion. Please chose one SE
>   website to post your question, wait a few days, and consider reposting on another SE website only
>   if you did not get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

**When a question is too broad**

Adapted from a comment by [EnergyNumber](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/44/energynumbers)

> Your question is very broad - too broad to handle in the handful of paragraphs that forms a good answer here. Can you narrow it down just to one specific angle you are chiefly interested in?

Answer (score 1):

## Welcome plus help with Latex

Something like this is useful when a new user asks what is almost surely a  homework question without formatting anything into LaTeX.

> Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

`Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!`

Answer (score 0):

## Welcome/Homework question

Something like this is useful when a new user asks what is almost surely a  homework question.

> Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://economics.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions) for information about asking homework-related questions. Cheers!

`Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://economics.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions) for information about asking homework-related questions. Cheers!`

Comment: When we develop our policy towards homework questions a little more, we should change the link in this comment to this other one: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Answer (score 0):

## Welcome plus "Homework question doesn't meet proper standards for this site"

> Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://economics.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions) for information about asking homework-related questions. This question seems like it doesn't quite meets the standards for homework-style questions and for this reason I would recommend that it be closed.

`Welcome to economics.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://economics.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions) for information about asking homework-related questions. This question seems like it doesn't quite meets the standards for homework-style questions and for this reason I would recommend that it be closed.`