# We have a help center!

Tags: discussion, faq

Although I am supposed to be a moderator around here, I only just dicovered that we have a [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help).

In particular, there is an article there "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)", which takes the form of a wiki for community editing. This is important because, among other reasons, authors are directed to the help center to figure out why their question has been put on hold. It is somewhat embarrassing that the information was not to be found there, but was instead hidden in an esoteric Meta post.

For now, I have copy/pasted our FAQ from Meta ([Welcome to Economics.SE!](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-se)) into the help centre, but please take a look and edit where necessary.

Comment: Good work - it clearly proves that you are not just "supposed" to be a moderator. From my experience with other sites I knew about the Help Center -but I was under the impression that it was SE-wide and not editable per site. (...)

Comment: I wouldn't know how to edit that.

Comment: AFAIK only moderators can edit that page.