# Accounting.se has failed - should we change our approach for accounting questions?

Tags: discussion

Currently, [our guidance](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-se) declares Accounting questions as Off-topic and reads:

> Accounting: Accounting is a separate discipline, and there is no
>   StackExchange site dedicated to that matter yet. But a proposal for an
>   Accounting.SE site is currently trying to get off the ground, you
>   could help.

Since the Accounting.se proposal has failed, I propose the following:

**Move Accounting questions from "off-topic" to "On-topic but", but subsumed under "Corporate finance/business economics" questions, since it is there that a meeting point with economics can be found.**

It is no secret that my approach to this site is rather inclusive than exclusive, and this proposal is in line with that.

Please upvote if you agree, downvote if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the overlap is too little to justify it. They are truly two different disciplines, with an almost entirely separate set of literature, methods, and interests. I see the point of inclusion, but it would come at the detriment of the site's attractiveness. Personally, adding plenty of accounting questions would decrease considerably my interest and effort in cleaning, answering, and using the site in general, as I would need to spend more time screening through questions which are not of my interest or knowledge. But that might be my selfish gene talking.

In any case, quant.SE or even money.SE are closer to us than accounting, and yet, we keep them separated.