# What can and should be done about cross-posting?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a couple of posts where people cross-posted their questions to another stack exchange, in both cases  stats.stackexchange.com . What should we do? Close them if they are verbatim or near-verbatim posts and tolerate them if they are customized enough to be distinct but related questions?

Answer (score 2):

Related: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

---

The consensus there seems to be this cross-posting should be discouraged, and that the better approach is to ask on one site, but have the question migrated if it turns out to be a better fit for another. We should probably add this to [our FAQ](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/welcome-to-economics-se).

As for what we should do ex post when someone cross-posts: my suggestion would be to add a comment explaining that this behaviour is not encouraged (we could write a template for this here: [List of comment templates](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/list-of-comment-templates)). We could then monitor the situation and close the question here if the cross-posted version seems to be getting more/better answers.