# List of decent homework questions

Tags: discussion, homework

This is a proposition related to the question [How Should We Deal with Homework Questions?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions).

I thought it might be useful to have a list of homework question that we consider as decent and as making the grade to be acceptable on SE.Economics.

This might usefully complement the guidelines in [How Should We Deal with Homework Questions?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions) in informing OP about the kind of standards we set for homework questions.

I suggest that you add homework questions you think would qualify as decent below and that people vote on the one they like the best in terms of the way they are formated, the effort put by the OP in trying to answer the question him or herself, whether the question is sophisticated enough...

Answer (score 2):

[How do I construct the score process of a Markov model and verify that it is a Martingale?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/how-do-i-construct-the-score-process-of-a-markov-model-and-verify-that-it-is-a-m)

Hopefully this is a decent homework-style question. The OP shows his work and where he is stuck.

Answer (score -4):

[Find Variable Cost](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/find-variable-cost)

What is good about the question:

- The OP really tried to solve the problem him or herself and came to the website with a question only after realizing he or she could not make sense of the solutions he or she was given.

Comment: This would seem to be below [the level we discussed previously](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/q/142/44)

Comment: It's a very basic question and would not show up if the textbook question was not wrong. I don't think it's a good example.