# How to ask a homework question?

Tags: discussion, faq, homework

## How to ask a homework question?

- Can I ask a homework question here?
- How do I ask a homework question on this website?
- What information should I include in a question about homework?
- Why don't you provide a complete answer to my question?

*This post was copied from that [meta.math.SX site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). I'm posting this question here to serve as a reference that we can point new users to. The answer should contain our conclusions to the question first asked here: [How Should We Deal with Homework Questions?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-should-we-deal-with-homework-questions)*

Comment: I hope that homework questions will not be welcome here.  If they are treated as welcome, then I for one will not participate.

Comment: Perhaps a good way to proceed is, instead of inviting answers, to turn the question into a wiki and allow people to edit it along the lines of the Welcome FAQ. If we have a question with several conflicting answers then the result might be more confusion.

Comment: Perhaps a "homework" tag as in mathematics.stackexchange? It would be good to allow users to create filters such that e.g. questions tagged "homework" are not shown to them. This may address the comment of @Steven Landsburg.

Comment: In the past the consensus has been to not allow homework questions because they tend to invite non-expert level questions. Homework questions have been allowed if they appear to be graduate level. I believe a "homework" tag will invite more non-expert level questions. So, I think that's why we haven't made one.